# Select distinct on one column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, distinct

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 500 
bk.firstname,
bk.surname,
bk.email,
county.region_id,
inspection.inspection_date

FROM
bken bk
LEFT OUTER JOIN county
  ON bk.county = county.code
LEFT OUTER JOIN inspection
  ON bk.inspid = inspection.inspid

WHERE
bk.firstname IS NOT NULL
AND bk.surname IS NOT NULL
AND bk.email IS NOT NULL
AND county.region_id IS NOT NULL
AND  county.region_id <> 10  
AND inspection_date > '04/01/2012 00:00:00.000'
AND inspection_date < '10/01/2012 00:00:00.000'
```

My goal is to obtain a sample of 500 different people.

Unfortunately this returns duplicate names (though the inspection dates are different) so I am trying to select distinct surnames to see if this will fix my problem. Can anyone help me do this?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Myabe you can use Group By for bk columns and MAX(inspection.inspection_date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group by` :

```
SELECT TOP 500 
bk.firstname,
bk.surname,
bk.email,
county.region_id,
max(inspection.inspection_date)

FROM
bken bk
LEFT OUTER JOIN county
  ON bk.county = county.code
LEFT OUTER JOIN inspection
  ON bk.inspid = inspection.inspid

WHERE
bk.firstname IS NOT NULL
AND bk.surname IS NOT NULL
AND bk.email IS NOT NULL
AND county.region_id IS NOT NULL
AND  county.region_id <> 10  
AND inspection_date > '04/01/2012 00:00:00.000'
AND inspection_date < '10/01/2012 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY 
bk.firstname,
bk.surname,
bk.email,
county.region_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use aggregate function for `inspection.inspection_date` fro example `min` with `group by` without `distinct` as below:

```
SELECT TOP 500 
bk.firstname,
bk.surname,
bk.email,
county.region_id,
min(inspection.inspection_date) as inspection_date    
FROM
bken bk
LEFT OUTER JOIN county
  ON bk.county = county.code
LEFT OUTER JOIN inspection
  ON bk.inspid = inspection.inspid

WHERE
bk.firstname IS NOT NULL
AND bk.surname IS NOT NULL
AND bk.email IS NOT NULL
AND county.region_id IS NOT NULL
AND  county.region_id <> 10  
AND inspection_date > '04/01/2012 00:00:00.000'
AND inspection_date < '10/01/2012 00:00:00.000'
group by bk.firstname,
         bk.surname,
         bk.email,
         county.region_id
```